# Our tour includes a comment that doesn't practice what we preach

Tags: discussion, comments, help-center

If you take a look at our [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour), specifically the "Improve posts by editing or commenting" section, we have a picture of a comment to [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/4828/39583). In my opinion, this comment is not asking for more information, or clarifying, and could plausibly stand on its own as an answer if it was expanded a little more. **Should we change our example question to include a better example of an ideal comment?**

Comment: What about that comment doesn't attempt to "clarify the meaning of a post?"

Comment: @Frostfyre It's on the edge... If it had been written a little differently I'd say it would be an excellent example. In general, however, I think we're looking for questions asking for clarity or statements clarifying possible interpretations. Not arguments against an answer. This is on the line, but I think for our tour it should be unambiguous.

Comment: All those comments appear to be obsolete now.  I wonder what would happen to the tour if I purged them...  (I don't see a way to change which question is used there.)

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

One, that's way too long. The example should be a comment such as "Could you please clarify ..."

Also, I completely agree. This comment is mostly not a good example. This is like a kindergarten teacher saying, "Remember to be nice! Also, Randy, your mom smells like a dead tortoise!" (Of course, the comment in question is not *rude*, just not extremely constructive.)

The best thing to do would be put an example like https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/111982/49656